# boolean keys[ ] getting NPE(Null Pointer Expression) java dont know how to assign it at the game start?

Tags: java, arrays

this is the main class which extends another class that contains the gameloop() .
keys() is checked insided the gameloop()

```
private boolean keys[] ;
public void keyPressed(KeyEvent ke){
    keys[ke.getKeyCode()] = true;
}

void keys(){

    if(keys[KeyEvent.VK_Q] == true){ //NPE here (Null Pointer Expression)
        stop();
    } 

    if(keys[KeyEvent.VK_SPACE] == true && jump== false){
        jump = true;
        cjump = true;
        jkptime = System.currentTimeMillis();
        _7zl2m.setVY(-0.4f);
    } 

    if(_7zl2m.getX() >= (bg.getWidth(null) - _7zl2m.getWidth()) && keys[KeyEvent.VK_RIGHT] == true || _7zl2m.getX() <= _7zl2m.getWidth() + 15 && keys[KeyEvent.VK_LEFT] == true || _7zl2m.getY() <= bg.getHeight(null) - 350 && keys[KeyEvent.VK_UP] == true || _7zl2m.getY() >= bg.getHeight(null) - 160 && keys[KeyEvent.VK_DOWN] == true){
        if(keys[KeyEvent.VK_RIGHT] == true || keys[KeyEvent.VK_LEFT] == true){
            _7zl2m.setVX(0.0f);
        }else if(keys[KeyEvent.VK_UP] == true || keys[KeyEvent.VK_DOWN] == true){
            _7zl2m.setVY(0.0f);
        }
    }else{
        if(keys[KeyEvent.VK_RIGHT] == true && jump == false){
            _7zl2m.setVX(0.2f);
        }

        else if(keys[KeyEvent.VK_LEFT] == true && jump == false){
            _7zl2m.setVX(-0.2f);
        }

        if(keys[KeyEvent.VK_UP] == true && jump == false){
            _7zl2m.setVY(-0.2f);
        }

        else if(keys[KeyEvent.VK_DOWN] == true && jump == false){
            _7zl2m.setVY(0.2f);
        }
    }

    if(keys[KeyEvent.VK_RIGHT] == false || keys[KeyEvent.VK_LEFT] == false){    
        _7zl2m.setVX(0.00f);
    }else if (keys[KeyEvent.VK_UP] == false || keys[KeyEvent.VK_DOWN] == false ){
        _7zl2m.setVY(0.0f);
    }
}

//release a key
public void keyReleased(KeyEvent ke){
    keys[ke.getKeyCode()] = false;
}
```

of course it will be null because i didnt press any key yet ... but how to fix this .
i already tried the Try Block

Comment: `_7zl2m` does not strike me as a particularly great variable name...

Comment: You haven't initialized it. Java does what you tell it to do.

Comment: @OliCharlesworth the game is called 7azal2oom so i wanted to call the main character class instance as 7zl2m but it cant be so _7zl2m was the first thing came to me :D

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis yes and i dont want to initializ it , it has to be initialized when i press a key ... so i cant work around that (if it has to be initialezed i dont know what to do)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should better be using `HashSet<Integer>` here, because you don't know what all keys would be pressed

initialize it like

```
private Set<Integer> keys = new HashSet<Integer>() ;
```

add values to it like

```
keys.add(someValue);
```

and check

```
keys.contains(someValue);
```

on release remove it from `Set`

```
keys.remove(someValue);
```

Comment: will try that , but how to check if the key has been pressed !!

Comment: `keys.contains(someValue);` if key code is present on this Set then it was pressed, right ?

Comment: that worked thanks very much , heading to make the AI for the Monsters ... ha ha ha -Evil laugh- :D :P

Answer (score 1):

Are you initializing `keys[]` anywhere? You could use smth like that `private boolean keys[] = new boolean[MAX_KEYS_AMOUNT]` .

Comment: no i didnt , will try that ... but what is the max key amount ? what should it be !

Comment: why would you initialize it with max possibility eagerly ?

Comment: It shouldn't be an issue if you track some small amount of keys (and its a boolean). I'm not arguing it's the best practice but looking at his code it's a fast way to see if that's the actual issue

Comment: it worked thanks , i wrote 500 as the max amount but cant get the left or right !!

Comment: If it's not you who controls KeyEvent keys definitions and you don't know what is the max of tracked keys (or max is very big) its better to use the approach Jigar suggested. 500 in such case wouldn't guarantee working code.

Comment: but one more problem , the character keeps walking when i release the key ... doesnt it set the false the right way !! here : `keys[ke.getKeyCode()] = false;`

Comment: never mind it was a logical error the left and right thing too , it was related :) ... thanks a lot :D